# Setting up two ordinary differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Just having a total blank at the moment, I realise that maybe this question would best be suited for a math forum but i assume *Mathematica* is needed in order to solve these equations. So the question explains that as time passes the two equations "decay", just no idea by how much. So basically there are two  ordinary, differential equations both decaying at different rates (I've attached them). I need to solve them for $t = 0$ to $120$ minutes.

Assume the initial conditions at $t = 0$ are

$\quad \quad A=B=0$

and that the parameters are

$\quad \quad K_1=0.5,\, K_2=2,\, n=10$

The ODEs are

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{0.5}{1+\left(\frac{B}{K_1}\right)^n}-0.2\,A$$
$$\frac{dB}{dt}=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{A}{K_2}\right)^n}-2\,B$$

I really have no idea mathematically nor *Mathematica*-wise on how to do this :(

Comment: Look at [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) & [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

Comment: Thanks, might sound stupid but I am still unsure of the relationship between t and both equations, is it that each value of A or B is affected by the amount calculated in the equation per 1 minute interval of t?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this (but this question is likely to be closed because it has been asked 10 000 times)

```
eqn1 = D[A[t], t] == 1/2/(1 + (B[t]/k1)^n) - 2/10 A[t]
eqn2 = D[B[t], t] == 1/(1 + (A[t]/k2)^n) - 2 B[t]
```

You can then solve for `A[t],B[t]`

```
sol=NDSolveValue[{eqn1, eqn2, A[0] == 0, B[0] == 0} /. {n -> 10, k1 -> 1/2, 
   k2 -> 2}, {A[t], B[t]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then you can plot the result:

```
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "... I have assumed arbitrarily that `n=1,k1=k2=1 and A[0]=0, B[0]=0`." doesn't seem to be the case. It appears that you substituted the OP values for the parameters. And the OP specified `A[0]=0`, `B[0]=0`. You should reconsider that remark.

Comment: No intent of telling you off. Just suggesting that you edit your answer to reflect the current state of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without understanding what is happening conceptually, I'm afraid that *Mathematica* probably won't help you much. You have a 2-by-2 system of differential equations, which I would recommend researching in general.

However, I like using *Mathematica* to visualize what is happening in a system, so here's some code!

```
k1 = 0.5; k2 = 2; n = 10;
StreamPlot[{.5/(1 + (y/k1)^n) - 0.2*x, 1/(1 + ((x/k2)^n) ) - 2*y}, 
  {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}]
```

[image: Direction Field]

I changed the notation to $x$ and $y$ instead of $A$ and $B$, but it's the same equations. This is a plot of the system's evolution over time for various initial conditions. I don't know where these equations came from, but this type of visualization helped me when I took Diff EQ's.

For some background info, try [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SystemsIntro.aspx)